# Navbar collapsing with bootstrap doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a navbar that collapses when I resize the screen, so I thought to use Bootstrap.

In the application.html.erb:

```
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="#">Some Store</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><%= link_to "Browse Products" %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Price List" %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Contact Us" %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Cart" %></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the Gemfile I have `gem 'bootstrap-sass'`

In the `application.css.scss` I wrote `@import 'bootstrap;'`

In the `application.js` I have `//= require bootstrap`

I don't understand why It doesn't work, I just copied from the bootstrap site

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your imports are correct, but your current markup is not. It doesn't match the markup and classes that I see in some of the examples. I first attempted to build from your markup while using the [sticky footer with fixed navbar example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/) in the bootstrap docs as a guide to get the markup to display properly. Here's how I adjusted your markup:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Some Store</a>
    </div> <!-- end div class="navbar-header" -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><%= link_to "Browse Products" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Price List" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Contact Us" %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Cart" %></li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- end div class="collapse navbar-collapse" -->
  </div> <!-- end div class="container" -->
</div> <!-- end div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" -->
```

If you look closely, I swapped the locations of the divs with classes `container` and `navbar-inner` and changed the class to `<div class="navbar-header">` that surrounds the collapse button. Then I had to change div surrounding the menu items to have class `navbar-collapse` instead of the `nav-collapse` that you had, otherwise the menu items disappear. In order for the button to work, I changed it from an `<a>` tag to a `<button>` tag as well as the `data-target="navbar-collapse"` attribute to correctly target the collapsible menu items. Once these changes were made, I had a functioning drop-down menu for window sizes < 768px.

And don't forget to add a style to your `<body>` tag for `padding-top:51px;` to guarantee your site content appears underneath the fixed navigation bar.

Hope that helps!

Chris

Answer (score 2):

Please check your application.html.erb file in the header section add this

`<meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`